# React hook that returns current tab in a chrome extension popup

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension using a react chrome extension boilerplate ([link](https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react))

Now I want to show my popup based on the current tab url. How can I query the current tab and can I do it in a hook way?

This is a function to get current tab, But I don't know how to use it in React and a hook.

```
async function getCurrentTab() {
    let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
    // `tab` will either be a `tabs.Tab` instance or `undefined`.
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
    return tab;
  }
```